# Address sanitizer link error due to '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL' mismatch

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, address-sanitizer, mismatch

I am having a strange issue with how one compiled executable can link with ASAN (Address sanitizer), but another cannot.

I am using CMake with Clang as my compiler, first I include and link my general purpose AzLib library, and also build a dummy executable that depends on it (Just to see if ASAN works there, and it does), but THEN I build my networking library AzNet (which depends on AzLib, and also uses Winsock as its targeted for Windows platform, so it links ws2_32.lib), and when i try to build an executable that depends on it, suddenly ASAN fails to link to it, saying that there is a mismatch for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL'.

Below is what NMake shows me:

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object Submodules/AzLib/AzLib/CMakeFiles/AzLib.dir/source/stub.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Linking CXX static library AzLib.lib
[ 20%] Built target AzLib
[ 30%] Building CXX object Submodules/AzLib/TestProject/CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/source/main.cpp.obj
[ 40%] Linking CXX executable TestProject.exe
[ 40%] Built target TestProject
[ 50%] Building CXX object AzNet/CMakeFiles/AzNet.dir/source/stub.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Linking CXX static library AzNet.lib
[ 60%] Built target AzNet
[ 70%] Building CXX object TestClient/CMakeFiles/TestClient.dir/source/main.cpp.obj
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable TestClient.exe
lld-link: error: /failifmismatch: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL':
>>> clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib(ubsan_type_hash_win.cpp.obj) has value 0
>>> CMakeFiles/TestClient.dir/source/main.cpp.obj has value 2
CLANG_~1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -fsanitize=address")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

project(AzNet)

add_subdirectory(Submodules)
add_subdirectory(AzNet)
add_subdirectory(TestClient)
add_subdirectory(TestServer)
```

And I build with this command: `cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 -S . -B build/`

I can't figure out this issue and it's very frustrating, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

If I try to compile on Release I get this error instead:

```
lld-link: error: /failifmismatch: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': >>> clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib(ubsan_type_hash_win.cpp.obj) has value MT_StaticRelease >>> CMakeFiles/TestClient.dir/source/main.cpp.obj has value MD_DynamicDebug
```

And when I try and fix that by changing to MT I instead get this:

```
lld-link: error: /INFERASANLIBS is not allowed in .drectve
lld-link: error: /INFERASANLIBS is not allowed in .drectve
CLANG_~1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

EDIT 2:
After researching into this issue it seems to be a problem with the standard library and lld, after specifying `add_compile_definitions(_DISABLE_STRING_ANNOTATION=1 _DISABLE_VECTOR_ANNOTATION=1)` in CMake, I am now able to compile on Release build, but Debug builds still fail, which is maybe related to `ws2_32.lib` that I link with? I'm not quite sure what to do about that, I need that library and I dont see a debug version of it.

Comment: It should be controlled with a flag - The address sanitizer should be used with specific flags because of how it works, Try to use ``add_definitions(-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0) `` and see if it helps.
You need to match your DLL build with the sanitizer to be able to use it.

Comment: The only external library I link with is `ws2_32.lib` (as its required for Winsock), the rest I compile without changing the CMake flags.
I am currently looking into if this one could be causing the issues...

Comment: After adding the `add_definitions(-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0)` I instead get this error
`lld-link: error: /failifmismatch: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary':
>>> clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib(ubsan_type_hash_win.cpp.obj) has value MT_StaticRelease
>>> CMakeFiles/TestClient.dir/source/main.cpp.obj has value MDd_DynamicDebug`

Comment: I want you to solve this error by yourself, a good hint that you make progress is that you go from one error to another. 
Ask yourself - what is ``MDd_DynamicDebug `` and how can I control it? A simple google search would yield you some results.
Also - see that it reports an error on the lib of asan: ``clang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.lib``.

Comment: Yep, I updated my main post with the progress, I changed to `MT` to be greeted with another error, which was an oddity from the standard library, which eventually I fixed aswell, and I am now able to build on Release, but on Debug is still the same issue as on the beginning

Comment: ASAN sometimes is tricky, I'm not sure it works on debug really.
From our experience we couldn't use Debug with it (Windows x64).
Anyway - these errors are all connected to ABI and compatibility issues - The Libs were built different and that was the problem.